# Verifying that a function lives in $H^{-1}(D)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory, dual-spaces

I have the following exercise (with also a solution), which I can't understand.

> Let $u(x,y)=(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})^{\alpha}$ and let $D$ be the unit disk. For which values of $\alpha$ is it true that $u \in H^{-1}(D)?$

The answer starts with:

> We must find a constant $C$ satisfying
>
> $$|\int_D uv | \leq D (\int_D |\nabla v|^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$ for every $v \in H_0^1(D)$

I cannot really understand why he's saying so. So, I know that $H^{-1}(D)$ is the space of bounded linear functionals from $H_0^1(D)$ to $\mathbb{R}$, while $u$ is *just a function, not a functional*.

So, I think he's using some kind of identification, like he's identifying $u$ with some functional, but I can't see which one!

Comment: Exactly. He is identifying u with a functional. Which one? You have it under your eyes

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro
I was thinking to $ H_0^1(D) \ni v \rightarrow (u,v)_{L^2(D)}$, but I don't see why that inequality would imply that the functional I've just defined is continuos...

Comment: Maybe I got it: if I identify $u$ with the functional $H_0^1(D) \ni v \rightarrow (u,v)_{L^2(D)}$, then requiring continuity of such a functional means that $$|\int_D uv| \leq ||u||_{L^2} ||v||_{L^2} \leq C_P ||u||_{L^2(D)} ||\nabla v||_{L^2(D)}$$ as I'm using the norm on $H_0^1(D)$. So the constant $C$ in the question is $C_P || u||_{L^2(D)}$? @GiuseppeNegro

Comment: Yes, that's it, but you do not need the first inequality (the one with the L2 norms of u and v), only the second matters. Also, do not invoke the L2 norm of u. Whether u is in L2 or not is irrelevant.

Comment: Ah, I see. Indeed the boundedness doesn't follow from C-S, it just wants the $C || \nabla v||_{L^2}$ term, as it's the norm of the starting space. My confusion came from the fact that I was expecting the full $H^1$ norm, then I realised that on $H_0^1$ we use this equivalent one. Thanks @GiuseppeNegro Btw, do you have any reference for this kind of topics (distributions, sobolev spaces) for an applied math people? I come from engeneeering but now I'm starting a MSc in applied math and all the references I find are old or pretty abstract. Thanks

Comment: I liked the books of Debnath-Mikusinski ("Hilbert Spaces") and of Kesavan ("Functional analysis etc...").